# SpringBoot @ExceptionHandler bubbles to Exception

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, exception, controller

I'm using Kotlin and SpringBoot 2.3. While testing I realized that `@ExceptionHandler(MissingKotlinParameterException::class)` in my controller doesn't work if I have an generic handler for uncaught exceptions with `@ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)`.

The exception always bubbles to generic exception handler. It's not the case with other exceptions like IllegalArgumentsException which the correct handler handles.

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Couldn't find the root cause. For the workaround, I check if the exception is of type `MissingKotlinParameterException` in the generic exception handler and then pass it to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException::class)`

instead of
`@ExceptionHandler(MissingKotlinParameterException::class)`

I had the same issue but with this above I solved the problem.

It is something to do with wrapper.